# Log4j2 trace comes twice for each logging for the given configuration file

Tags: java, log4j2

My logging code:-

```
    public void run(ApplicationArguments applicationArguments) throws Exception {
    logger.debug("Debugging log");
    logger.info("Info log");
    logger.warn("Hey, Thi s is a warning!");
    logger.error("Oops! We have an Error. OK");
    logger.fatal("Damn! Fatal error. Please fix me.");
}
```

My log4j2.xml file:-

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
        <Properties>
            <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
                %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p  [%t] - (%F:%L) - %m%n
            </Property>
        </Properties>

        <Appenders>
            <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
                <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
            </Console>

            <!-- Rolling File Appender -->
            <RollingFile name="FileAppender" fileName="logs/currency_exchange.log"
                         filePattern="logs/currency_exchange-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}-%i.log">
                <PatternLayout>
                    <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
                <Policies>
                    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" />
                    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
                </Policies>
                <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
            </RollingFile>
        </Appenders>

        <Loggers>
            <AsyncLogger name="com.example.log4j2demo" level="info"
                         additivity="info">
                <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
                <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender" />
            </AsyncLogger>

            <Root level="info">
                <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
                <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender" />
            </Root>
        </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```

As you can see the output in the console as:-

[image]

Also, the log entry is twice in the file. I want only one line of each log. The one with the link as this one:-

09-02-2020 10:36:02.280  INFO  [main] -(Log4j2DemoApplication.java:21) - Info log

What is wrong? How to fix it?

Comment: Please comment on of your Loggers tag and test again, for example, comment `AsyncLogger` and test

Comment: additivity should be "false", not "info".

Comment: Also, I was expecting my file log file will be have time stampe as mentioend in the this tag:     <RollingFile name="FileAppender" fileName="logs/currency_exchange.log"
                     filePattern="logs/currency_exchange-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}-%i.log" . But I have file only currency_exchange.log why no time stampe.

Comment: @masiboo I've edited my answer to address the file name question you mentioned in the comment. However, I strongly suggest that you take some time to understand the philosophy of Log4j especially the loggers hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given a wrong value in the additivity value of both loggers. Setting the additivity value to false will solve the messages duplication issue as it will prevent the logger from inheriting from its ancestor, in this case the root logger.

For the file name issue you mention in your comment: the filePattern property is used to generate the rolled log file name, that's the one on which you no longer write but keep for auditing/troubleshooting purposes, not the currently active one whose name is defined in the "fileName" tag instead.

Comment: Thanks for the information. After setting additivity value to false, it worked. But when I copied the same log4j2.xml to another project. Of course, I changed the package name for the new project. There I have only one line log without the link waht i can click and go to the logline. How to get the link in log console out?